# How to get multiple checkboxes in one meta field

Tags: custom-field

I can manage to show one checkbox using [woocommerce products custom fields](http://www.remicorson.com/mastering-woocommerce-products-custom-fields/)

However, I need to show multiple values from multiple checkboxes in my admin area. I have the following code:

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="myoption[option_one]" value="1"<?php checked( isset( $options['option_one'] ) ); ?> />
 <input type="checkbox" name="myoption[option_two]" value="1"<?php checked( isset( $options['option_two'] ) ); ?> />
```

Now how would I be able to save them into one meta field? Similar to the idea below?

```
$product_field_type =  $_POST['product_field_type'];
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_product_field_type_ids', $product_field_type );
```

**EDIT**

Ok so I have been able to define a custom box in my product page. But my checkboxes aren't storing! What am I missing here?

```
   /* Define the custom box */
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'wpse_61041_add_custom_box' );

/* Do something with the data entered */
add_action( 'save_post', 'wpse_61041_save_postdata' );

/* Adds a box to the main column on the Post and Page edit screens */
function wpse_61041_add_custom_box() {
  add_meta_box( 'wpse_61041_sectionid', 'title_color', 'wpse_61041_inner_custom_box', 'product', 'normal', 'high' );
}
/* Prints the box content */
function wpse_61041_inner_custom_box($post)
{
    // Use nonce for verification
    wp_nonce_field( 'wpse_61041_wpse_61041_field_nonce', 'wpse_61041_noncename' );

    // Get saved value, if none exists, "default" is selected
    $saved = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'title_color', true);
    if( !$saved )
        $saved = 'default';

    $fields = array(
        'red'       => __('Red', 'wpse'),
        'green'     => __('Green', 'wpse'),
        'blue'      => __('Blue', 'wpse'),
        'default'   => __('Default', 'wpse'),
    );

    foreach($fields as $key => $label)
    {
        printf(
            '<input type="checkbox" name="title_color" value="%1$s" id="title_color[%1$s]" %3$s />'.
            '<label for="title_color[%1$s]"> %2$s ' .
            '</label><br>',
            esc_attr($key),
            esc_html($label),
            checked($saved, $key, false)
        );
    }
}

   /* When the post is saved, saves our custom data */
   function wpse_61041_save_postdata( $post_id ) 
   {
        // verify if this is an auto save routine. 
      // If it is our form has not been submitted, so we dont want to do anything
      if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
          return;

      // verify this came from the our screen and with proper authorization,
      // because save_post can be triggered at other times
      if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['wpse_61041_noncename'], 'wpse_61041_wpse_61041_field_nonce' ) )
          return;

      if ( isset($_POST['title_color']) && $_POST['title_color'] != "" ){
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'title_color', $_POST['title_color'] );
      } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using Advanced Custom Fields Plugin with get_field( "facilities" ) in my template.

I created a Field Group and added facilities as checkboxes. Much faster than checking my code. I would've liked to add the checkboxes straight into WooCommerce but this was a time saver and  no more time is needed to fix the original code.

Comment: +1 for meeting your deadline. ACF is a fantastic tool, but don't be defeated! Having the knowledge to write your own post meta boxes/fields will come in extremely useful later on!

Comment: Thanks Eric, I agree, I will test out your solution later because it would be useful indeed :)

Answer (score 1):

Sander, I think you were EXTREMELY CLOSE. It looks like the data should have been saving.. but [`checked`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/checked) directly compares two values, as far as I know. You may have better luck with this.

```
printf(
            '<input type="checkbox" name="title_color" value="%1$s" id="title_color[%1$s]" %3$s />'.
            '<label for="title_color[%1$s]"> %2$s ' .
            '</label><br>',
            esc_attr($key),
            esc_html($label),
            in_array($key, (array) $saved )
        );
```